# Get my script to wirte in a excel if installed are suceed or not

Tags: excel, powershell

I have a script who install many program some with choco (the basic one) and other like Autocad etc.. , script also modify some windwos paramater

everything is in function because i need to select specific roles at the begining depend on what type of machine i run the script

```
$logs +=Rename-ComputerFunction
        $logs +=Set-FranceTimeZoneAndSync
        $logs +=Install-AgentMonitoring
        $logs +=Install-AppsWithChocolateyENR
        $logs +=Install-SoftEther
        $logs +=Import-VPN-settings
        $logs +=Configure-NetworkInterface
        $logs +=Install-Draftsight
        $logs +=Copy-SignatureFiles
        $logs +=Uninstall-Office365Apps
        $logs +=Install-Office365Apps
        $logs +=Install-Fonts
```

so i get logs in a txt at the end

but i also have some excel (one excel by type of computer) and i want if i run my script let say for the PC_Agence that my script if the command are executed succefully or not , write in the excel_PC_Agence if is succes or not for each of my function

In the excel i have some cells with name in it like :

Part of my script for better understanding : "Police Clients" who refer to my function Install-Fonts

```
function PC_AGENCE {
    Write-Host "Running PC_AGENCE Setup"

    # Initialize an empty array to store the logs
    $logs = @()

    # Call the functions you need for the PC_AGENCE setup
        $logs += Rename-ComputerFunction
        $logs += Set-FranceTimeZoneAndSync
        $logs += Install-AgentMonitoring
        $logs += Install-AppsWithChocolateyPC_AGENCE
        $logs += Install-SoftEther
        $logs += Import-VPN-settings
        $logs += Configure-NetworkInterface
        $logs += Install-Draftsight
        $logs += Create-Shortcuts
        $logs += Copy-SignatureFiles
        $logs += Uninstall-Office365Apps
        $logs += Install-Office365Apps
        $logs += Install-Fonts
        $logs += Install-Setup-ConnectionClient
        $logs += Copy-Files-nepstool
        $logs += Copy-FilesToTemplates
        $logs += Copy-FilesToBuildingBlocks
        $logs += Set-OfficeTemplatesPath
        #$logs += Install-HAMACHI
        $logs += Install-eDrawings
        $logs += Install-ClimaWin2012
        $logs += Install-ClimaWin2020
        $logs += Install-EcoDiag
        $logs += Install-BBS_LDK
        $logs += Install-pleiades
        $logs += Install-ZWCAD
        $logs += Install-ZWCAD_LanguageFR
        $logs += Activate-ZWCADLicense
        $logs += Install-Autocad2024LT
        $logs += Install-Revit2022
        $logs += Remove-DellOptimizerCore
        $logs += Remove-DellOptimizer
        $logs += Configure-SleepModeSettings
        $logs += Configure-ClosingLidSettings
        $logs += Disable-FastStartup

    # Get the current date and time
    $date = Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMdd_HHmm"

    # Define the path to your log file
    $logFilePath = "$driveLetter\Config PC\Logs\log_${date}.txt"
    
    # Join the log messages into a final log string with newline characters in between
    $finalLog = $logs -join "`n"

    # Write the final log to a file
    $finalLog | Out-File -FilePath $logFilePath
    
    Prompt-For-Restart
}


# add other function here...

# Create a hash table with role names and corresponding script blocks
$roleActions = @{
    "1" = { PC_AGENCE }
    "2" = { Projeteur }
    "3" = { BAT }
    "4" = { ENR }
    "5" = { STR }
    "6" = { IND }
    "7" = { F0R }
    "8" = { TR6 }
    "9" = { Assistant }
    "10" = { TEST }
}

# List options for user
Write-Host "Select a Role:"
Write-Host "1. PC_AGENCE"
Write-Host "2. Projeteur"
Write-Host "3. BAT"
Write-Host "4. ENR"
Write-Host "5. STR"
Write-Host "6. IND"
Write-Host "7. F0R"
Write-Host "8. TR6"
Write-Host "9. Assistant"
Write-Host "10. GRE"

# Get user input
$choice = Read-Host "Enter your choice"

if ($roleActions.ContainsKey($choice)) {
    & $roleActions[$choice]
} else {
    Write-Host "Invalid choice"
}
```

i tried some :

```
function Update-ExcelChecklist {
    param (
        [string]$excelPath,
        [bool]$success
    )

    if ($success) {
        $excel = Import-Excel -Path $excelPath -NoHeader


        # Find the row and column containing "Police Nepsen"
        $rowIndex, $colIndex = $null, $null
        foreach ($row in $excel) {
            foreach ($col in $row.PSObject.Properties) {
                if ($col.Value -eq "Police Nepsen") {
                    $rowIndex = $row.Index
                    $colIndex = [System.Array]::IndexOf($row.PSObject.Properties.Name, $col.Name) + 1
                    break
                }
            }
            if ($rowIndex -ne $null -and $colIndex -ne $null) {
                break
            }
        }

        if ($rowIndex -ne $null -and $colIndex -ne $null) {
            # Convert to Excel's 1-based indexing
            $excelRow = $rowIndex + 2
            $excelCol = [char]($colIndex + 64)

            # Export with the specified cell background color set to green
            $excel | Export-Excel -Path $excelPath -ClearSheet -AutoSize -PassThru |
                Set-Format -Range "$excelCol$excelRow" -BackgroundColor Green
        }
        else {
            Write-Host "Police Nepsen not found in the Excel file."
        }
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "Fonts installation failed, not updating Excel file."
    }
}
```

```
# Example of calling Update-ExcelChecklist
$installResult = Install-Fonts
$success = $installResult -match "Success"
Update-ExcelChecklist -excelPath $excelPath -success $success
```

but get this :

```
Select a Role:
1. PC_AGENCE
2. Projeteur
3. BAT
4. ENR
5. STR
6. IND
7. F0R
8. TR6
9. Assistant
Enter the number of your selection : 7
Installing font: Exo-SemiBold
Installing font: Exo2-Black
Installing font: Exo2-BlackItalic
Installing font: Exo2-Bold
Installing font: Exo2-BoldItalic
Installing font: Exo2-ExtraBold
Installing font: Exo2-ExtraBoldItalic
Installing font: Exo2-ExtraLight
Installing font: Exo2-ExtraLightItalic
Installing font: Exo2-Italic
Installing font: Exo2-Light
Installing font: Exo2-LightItalic
Installing font: Exo2-Medium
Installing font: Exo2-MediumItalic
Installing font: Exo2-Regular
Installing font: Exo2-SemiBold
Installing font: Exo2-SemiBoldItalic
Installing font: Exo2-Thin
Installing font: Exo2-ThinItalic
Installing font: PT SansItalic
Installing font: PTSans Bold Italic
Installing font: PTSansBold
Installing font: PTSansRegular
Police Nepsen not found in the Excel file.

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

but this code is good for one thing buti dont think i can use it based on the role i select and for every function i want

Comment: That's a lot of code and text, and it's not readily apparent what, specifically, your problem is. Please consider [edit]ing your question to focus on just the core of the problem, along with expected vs. actual output, ideally in the form of an [mcve].